# Maven: Command to update repository after adding dependency to POM

Tags: maven-2, maven-dependency

I've added a new dependency to my POM.

Is there a simple command I can run to download this dependency to my repository?

Comment: For those looking on how to do this in a Spring Boot project: use `mvnw` to call the wrapper layer. The commands on this page work with it.

Comment: @G_V Can you expand on that? How would we use `mvnw`` to add the dependencies?

Answer (score 248, accepted):

`mvn install` (or `mvn package`) will always work.

You can use `mvn compile` to download compile time dependencies or `mvn test` for compile time and test dependencies but I prefer something that always works.

Comment: Thanks, I also discovered that adding it to the pom in STS will automatically download it for you.

Comment: @Andrew Spencer's reply is more accurate - `mvn dependency:xxx` deal with dependencies only and don't do any additional stuff - and that what the question was about.

Comment: At times, 'mvn package' may not update dependencies. Has happened to me more than once.One needs to run 'mvn dependency:resolve' in such cases

Comment: @BinitaBharati, you can add a -U to the Maven command line to force dependency downloads.  This is useful if Maven doesn't download an updated dependency because of a cache timeout.

Comment: Hi I have `<dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20180813</version>
        </dependency>
` in dependencies inside pom.xml but mvn install throws error `package org.json.simple does not exist` during compilation

Comment: @Kishan Ask a new question. Show the layout of your project (especially where the `import` happens) and whether you use a multi-module build.

Comment: Ok @Aron sure! Would add it soon

Answer (score 842):

Per [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8564244/587365), Maven will download the dependency as part of `mvn compile`, `mvn install` etc. [By default it happens](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/resolve-mojo.html) in the `generate-sources` phase of the [default lifecycle](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference) - so invoking any phase from `generate-sources` onward will download dependencies.

**If you want to only download dependencies without doing other activities such as compilation**, then it's:

```
mvn dependency:resolve
```

Or to download a single dependency:

```
mvn dependency:get -Dartifact=groupId:artifactId:version
```

If you need to download from a specific repository, you can specify that with `-DrepoUrl=...`

Comment: I get this error when I run that command: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:get (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: The parameters 'repositoryUrl' for goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:get are missing or invalid -> [Help 1].  Specifying -DrepositoryUrl=... doesn't work.

Comment: I think I've found the solution.  The parameter should be "repoUrl" and not "repositoryUrl".

Comment: Doesn't solve the issue for me: the I run `mvn package -o` right after — I get error that plugins can not be downloaded. Running `mvn dependency:resolve-plugins` doesn't fully solve the issue either.

Comment: Your repository URLs might be missing/wrong. In any case, I don't think this answer is the answer to the problem you're having. This answer covers the case when Maven can find all the artefacts it needs in the configured repositories.

Comment: I don't care if you are a believer or not, a christian or not... God bless you this awesome simple answer.

Comment: I noted that mvn eclipse:eclipse does not download all dependencies, because if i run eclipse plugin first and after mvn dependency:resolve, more jars are downloaded in m2 repo. I guess that eclipse:eclipse is somehow a plugin that readout the pom and configure eclipse workspace adding proper classpath and buildpath in order to resolve classes, generated sources and so inside the eclipse IDE,  but may you tell me where the eclipse:eclipse command will end its work in the maven lifecycle?

Comment: I don't know - worth asking as a top-level question if you need an answer.

Comment: `If you want to only download dependencies without doing anything else` Could someone elaborate what else could be done besides downloading the dependencies? Is there something I should do besides downloading the dependencies?

Comment: @Basti dependencies will be downloaded when running Maven lifecycle phases such as `maven compile` so for most people, that's all you need. But sometimes people want to download dependencies for whatever reason, without also invoking any other activities bound to any lifecycle stages. And that's what this question is for. In other words, if you're just using Maven normally, you don't need this question/answer.

Comment: I updated the answer to first point out that it happens anyway in most lifecycle phases. When I first wrote the answer, it was below the other answer that explained this.

Answer (score 13):

I know it is an old question now, but for users who are using `Maven` plugin with `Eclipse`  under `Windows`, you have two options:

1. If you got Maven installed as a standalone application:

   You can use the following command in the `CMD` under your project
   path:

   ```
   mvn eclipse:eclipse
   ```

   It will update your repository with all the missing jars, according
   to your dependencies in your `pom.xml` file.
2. If you haven't got Maven installed as a standalone application you
   can follow these steps on your eclipse:

   Right click on the `project` ->`Run As` -- >`Run configurations`.

   Then select `mavenBuild`.

   Then click `new` button to create a configuration of the selected
   type .Click on Browse workspace then select your project and in
   goals specify `eclipse:eclipse`

You can refer to **[how to run the command mvn eclipse:eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15633951/how-to-run-the-command-mvn-eclipseeclipse)** for further details.

Comment: Running eclipse:eclipse after dependency:resolve helped me see downloaded jars in eclipse, thanks!

Comment: While this answer will help the poor folk stuck with Eclipse, I strongly recommend that anyone using Eclipse find a better alternative. Especially if you're going to be using Maven. Netbeans and IntelliJ are light years ahead.

Comment: @64BitBob Assuming that Netbeans and IntelliJ are better than eclipse, we should always give a solution for those who use it. :)

Comment: I see that the plugin is not available anymore in marketplace but yes it works in Eclipse 2020 without downloading anything. I wonder if mvn eclipse:eclipse is the command sent by eclipse itself when we rightclick->Maven->Update Project...

Comment: @Paolo In my opinion they have automatically added the plugin in new versions of Eclipse, and yes I think it's the same command behind the "Update project" option.

Comment: In 2023 I think using `eclipse:eclipse` is really bad advice. Everything should work out of box if you just import project as 'Existing Maven Projects'.

Answer (score -1):

Pay attention to your dependency scope
I was having the issue where when I invoke clean compile via Intellij, the pom would get downloaded, but the jar would not. There was a xxx.jar.lastUpdated file created. Then realized that the dependency scope was test, but I was triggering the compile. I deleted the repos, and triggered the mvn test, and issue was resolved.