# how to run the command mvn eclipse:eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven

I'm following [these instructions](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-ide-eclipse.html), but having problems with running commands like `mvn eclipse:eclipse`.

How and where shall I run the command?

My setup:

- Windows 7 32bit
- Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
- Version: Juno Service Release 2
- Build id: 20130225-0426
- m2e - maven integration for eclipse v 1.3.0

I installed the m2e via the plugin installation in Eclipse.

Comment: BTW broken link about the `Maven` guide for `Eclipse`

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The m2e plugin uses it's own distribution of Maven, packaged with the plugin.

In order to use Maven from command line, you need to have it installed as a standalone application. [**Here**](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-install-maven-in-windows/) is an instruction explaining how to do it in Windows

Once Maven is properly installed (i.e. be sure that `MAVEN_HOME`, `JAVA_HOME` and `PATH` variables are set correctly): you must run `mvn eclipse:eclipse` from the directory containing the `pom.xml`.

Answer (score 101):

Right click on the project

->`Run As` --> `Run configurations`.

Then select `Maven Build`

Then click *new* button to create a configuration of the selected type. Click on `Browse workspace` (now is `Workspace...`) then select your project and in goals specify `eclipse:eclipse`

Comment: This is the correct answer. The accepted answer also works but requires the installation of a local maven repo.

Comment: @JPCF: agreed. You do not _need to have [Maven] installed as a standalone application_ as the accepted answer suggests. Exactly what I was looking for, thanks.

Comment: what happend if I actually want is execute a goal like: [[mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=<group-id> \
  -DartifactId=<artifact-id> \
  -Dversion=<version> \
  -Dpackaging=<type-of-packaging> \
  -Dfile=<path-to-file> \
  -DrepositoryId=<id-to-map-on-server-section-of-settings.xml> \
  -Durl=<url-of-the-repository-to-deploy>]]

Answer (score 5):

I don't think one needs it any more. The latest versions of Eclipse have Maven plugin enabled. So you will just need to import a **Maven project** into Eclipse and no more as an existing project. Eclipse will create the needed .project, .settings, .classpath files based on your pom.xml and environment settings (installed Java version, etc.) . The earlier versions of Eclipse needed to have run the command `mvn eclipse:eclipse` which produced the same result.

Comment: The problem is that Eclipse tends to import a project as a "Maven" project w/o identifying its Java facet. So once we import the project, we have to point-n-click to get that going. Using `mvn eclipse:eclipse` before importing the projects set the appropriate facet (most of the time... caveat emptor.)

Answer (score 3):

Besides the powerful options on the "Run Configurations.." on a well configured project you'll see  the maven tasks on the Run As as well.

[image]