# Maven dependencies not reflecting in Eclipse project

Tags: eclipse, maven

In my jsf project. How can i add mysql libraries in **maven dependency** ?
I am trying to copy and paste. It says i cant do. I also tried to add library in build path. it didnt work. I am using Eclipse.
[This is my maven tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLO1X.png)

This is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>jsflab</groupId>
  <artifactId>jsflab</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.6</source>
          <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.richfaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>richfaces</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-validator -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.6</version>
</dependency>


  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: paste your pom file here, currently it seems your pom does not contain mysql jars

Comment: I shared my pom.xml @kuhajeyan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add following to your pom.xml file

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.39</version>
</dependency>
```

Edit: If the pom is externally updated, then we have to update the maven project in Eclipse

**Package Explorer -> right click on project > Maven > Update project**

Comment: @AnılŞenocak refresh eclipse project. Package Explorer -> right click on project > Maven > Update project. Also try building the project using `mvn install`

Comment: Thanks it worked. @sidgate

Package Explorer -> right click on project > Maven > Update project.

Answer (score 2):

Add below snippet into your `pom.xml`

```
<properties>
            <mysql.version>6.0.3</mysql.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>${mysql.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

After this clean your project and build

To build through command prompt [see this](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/maven/maven-commands.html)

by eclipse [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15633951/how-to-run-the-command-mvn-eclipseeclipse)

Answer (score 1):

In your pom.xml Add MySQL dependency :

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.6</version>
</dependency>
```

You can find all Maven dependeny from here [MVNRepository](https://mvnrepository.com/)

Answer (score 0):

you have to run update project from maven options or you can run maven install to download the dependencies.