# Accidentally changed packaging to 'war'. How to revert to 'jar' properly?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, web.xml, packaging

I have created a Maven project with the facets: Java, JPA and Utility Module.
In the pom.xml I set packaging to jar. Everything worked fine.

Later I accidentally set the packaging to war and Eclipse started to complain that "web.xml is missing and failOnMissingWebXml is set to true".
I changed the packaging back to jar but Eclipse is still complaining.

How can I fix this?

Comment: ALT-F5 ("Maven -> Update Project...")

Comment: That didn't work. Maybe it's worth noting that the project has a parent project which has packaging set to pom. But I don't think that has anything to do with it.

Comment: you can close your project, recreate it with `mvn eclipse:eclipse` then reload it

Comment: Thanks Nicolas Filotto. Your answer worked. I used this topic (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15633951/how-to-run-the-command-mvn-eclipseeclipse) as a reference on how to use the "mvn eclipse:eclipse" command. Afterwards I removed the project from the workspace and added it again. Then the problem was gone. I don't know how to mark your answer as correct. Is that because it's only a comment and not really an answer?