# M2E in VsCode (or terminal) as Apache Maven Eclipse Plugin has retired

Tags: maven, java-8, visual-studio-code, m2eclipse, eclipse-classpath

I have to update `.classpath`, `.project` and `.settings` for a Maven project in VS Code. I read that `mvn eclipse:eclipse` has been retired and I tried that but it doesn't gives me correct files.

How can I use M2E in VScode to regenerate these files? Or, how can I use M2E from the terminal (independent of IDE)?

Reference:

- [Apache Maven Eclipse Plugin (RETIRED) - Introduction](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/)
- [maven - how to run the command mvn eclipse:eclipse - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15633951/how-to-run-the-command-mvn-eclipseeclipse)

Comment: m2e is an Eclipse plug-in to integrate Maven with Eclipse. What has it got to do with VSCode or the terminal?

Comment: @greg-449 the headless version of m2e is being used in the RedHat Java extension for Vscode. It uses language server and can be used from any IDE or terminal.

Comment: Looks like this was asked at https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/995 also