# Maven dependency - Maven Install / update project

Tags: eclipse, maven

Maven Install downloads the dependencies from POM or update Project option does it ?

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse, Maven install runs the following command on your project: `mvn install`

Which automatically updates any dependencies, then builds all modules and installs them in the local repository.

However, choosing "build project" in Eclipse automatically invokes Maven.

Sources:

[Building a Project with Maven](https://maven.apache.org/run-maven/)

[Maven: Command to update repository after adding dependency to POM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8563960/maven-command-to-update-repository-after-adding-dependency-to-pom)

Answer (score 0):

Maven Update - This will bring the jars downloaded in the repository into the eclipse
Maven Install - This will perform the Maven life cycle till install (Validate -> Compile -> test-> package ->verify -> Install)