# Alfresco solr tracking failed

Tags: java, maven, solr, alfresco, alfresco-maven

So in term of chronology of my project :
I generated an alfresco maven repository with `mvn archetype:generate -Dfilter=org.alfresco:` (Alfresco Platform JAR archetype) then I added a custom content model XML file in repo-test/src/main/resources/alfresco/module/repo-test/model/scModel.xml which contains what you can find [here](http://ecmarchitect.com/alfresco-developer-series-tutorials/content/tutorial/tutorial.html#creating-a-custom-content-model) after I registered the new model by adding these lines in `repo-test/src/main/resources/alfresco/module/repo-test/context/bootstrap-context.xml` :

```
<!-- Registration of new models -->
<bean id="${project.artifactId}_dictionaryBootstrap" parent="dictionaryModelBootstrap" depends-on="dictionaryBootstrap">
    <property name="models">
        <list>
            <value>alfresco/module/${project.artifactId}/model/scModel.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The installation went well. But when I try to launch the run.sh it gets stuck repeating this :

```
2017-05-02 18:34:00,192  ERROR [solr.tracker.AbstractTracker] [org.alfresco.solr.AlfrescoCoreAdminHandler@1bb39ea_Worker-21] Tracking failed
 org.alfresco.error.AlfrescoRuntimeException: 04020731 GetModelsDiff return status is 404
        at org.alfresco.solr.client.SOLRAPIClient.getModelsDiff(SOLRAPIClient.java:1181)
        at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.ModelTracker.trackModelsImpl(ModelTracker.java:256)
        at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.ModelTracker.trackModels(ModelTracker.java:214)
        at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.ModelTracker.doTrack(ModelTracker.java:174)
        at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.AbstractTracker.track(AbstractTracker.java:190)
        at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.TrackerJob.execute(TrackerJob.java:54)
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:216)
        at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:563)
```

Anyone knows how to solve this issue ?
I also tried to launch it without modifying anything (I created another project) but got an error after a night of compiling :

```
INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 58:03 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-05-02T19:39:08+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 223M/224M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.alfresco.maven.plugin:alfresco-maven-plugin:3.0.0:it (start-alfresco) on project content-tutorial-repo: Unable to execute mojo: N'a pas pu démarrer Tomcat: Failed to start component [StandardServer[-1]]: Failed to start component [StandardService[Tomcat]]: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat]]: A child container failed during start -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: de /schlichtherle/truezip/fs/FsLockController$1Sync
```

P.S : I'm on Raspbian 32bits...

Comment: Make sure that you have downloaded all the maven dependencies. Because when you launch it first time maven takes time to download dependencies.

Comment: @KintuBarot ok yes that was the problem, thanks to the command found in [Maven: Command to update repository after adding dependency to POM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8563960/maven-command-to-update-repository-after-adding-dependency-to-pom) i could resolve my issue ! Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to update my dependencies to solve this issue, if you experience a problem like this try the command in [Maven: Command to update repository after adding dependency to POM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8563960/maven-command-to-update-repository-after-adding-dependency-to-pom)