# How to install this maven dependency from scratch?

Tags: java, apache, maven, sdk

I am setting up an environment for Overledger in Java. How to install the Overledger SDK as a maven dependency. In documentation, only this information is given: 
[image: Source: Documentation]

I have never installed SDK in Java using maven, so it would be great if you'd explain me from scratch.

Comment: do you know what a maven dependency is/does? all you need to do is run a build/install and the dependencies are downloaded and made available for your project

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maven: Command to update repository after adding dependency to POM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8563960/maven-command-to-update-repository-after-adding-dependency-to-pom)

Comment: 1. Open the POM.xml file for your project 2. Add your desired dependency, inside the <dependencies> </dependencies> tag which is already present there 3. Right click on the project >> Maven >> Update Project. This will download all the dependencies. You can validate the same by checking the Maven Dependencies section got created for the project.

Answer (score 3):

The documentation should read "Developers have to *declare* ..." instead of "Developers have to *install* ...".

See [Maven POM Reference, Dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Dependencies) for how to declare the dependency in your project's POM (i.e. `pom.xml`):

```
<project ...>

  ...

  <dependencies>

    ...

    <dependency>
      <groupId>network.quant</groupId>
      <artifactId>overledger-sdk-bundle</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0-alpha.2</version>
    </dependency>

    ...

  </dependencies>

  ...

<project>
```

At the next Maven build (or project update in your IDE) it will be downloaded from the [Maven Central repository](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:network.quant%20AND%20a:overledger-sdk-bundle&core=gav) to your local repository (located in `~/.m2/repository` by default). From then on the dependency's classes can be used in your project's code.

Answer (score -2):

Add the provided Maven dependency to your pom.xml in your Maven project.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    ...>

    ...

    <build>
        ...
    </build>

    <dependencies>

        ...

        <dependency>
            <groupId>network.quant</groupId>
            <artifactId>overledger-sdk-bundle</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-alpha.2</version>
        </dependency>

        ...

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

more Maven Getting Started: https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/

Comment: If you make an example please follow the convention over configuration paradigm...

Comment: @khmarbaise, is this better?